# Microsoft Dataverse Web API - Retrieve File Content

Tags: postman, powerapps, webapi, dataverse

It must be very simple, but I can't figure out out how to retrieve a File content from a Microsoft Dataverse table.

I have a table called **quotes**. This table has a column of type File "cra7f_ficheiropricing" to which I have previously uploaded a file. Using Postman, I want to retrieve the content of the file as a binary file.

In the following, I was able to filter the quote I wanted (record of the table), the results are bellow.

[image]

I have tried the
[Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/overview) but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked this out?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/file-attributes

**Example**: REST download with chunking

HTTP Request

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/accounts(id)/myfileattribute/$value
Headers:
Range: bytes=0-1023/8192
```

HTTP Response

```
206 Partial Content
Body: byte[]
```

So if I get this correctly, you'd have to try this in your concrete case:

```
 GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.1/quotes(-your-guid-here-)/cra7f_ficheiropricing/$value
```

Comment: $value made the difference. Thank you.

Comment: @marc_s This retrieves the content of the file in the response body. Is there a way to make the browser download that file ?